# RingCentral REST API SMS Error

Tags: json, rest, ringcentral

RingCentral RESTful API accept JSON input for SMS. But on SMS JSON input it is giving this error reply:-

```
{
  "message" : "Parameter [to] is invalid",
  "errorCode" : "InvalidParameter",
  "parameterName" : "to"
}
```

However, I'm sending correct input as per their [documentation](https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-docs/latest/index.html#!#TextMessages.html)

They require input in this format:-

```
{
   "to": [{"phoneNumber": "14151003732"}],
   "from": {"phoneNumber": "16509100010"}, 
   "text": "Test SMS message"
}
```

My JSON input string is:

```
{ "to": [{"phoneNumber": "+1XXXXXXXXXX"}], "from": {"phoneNumber": "+1XXXXXXXXXX"}, "text": "This is a message" }
```

Can anyone please point where I'm making mistake? I can post PHP code if required.

Comment: Your JSON works fine for me using the RingCentral PHP SDK. Can you post some of your code?

Comment: You might want to remove the plus symbol from your phoneNumbers.

Something else which might cause this is if you're trying to send an SMS to a valid extension of type User or Take Message Only (Voicemail). I've not tested with this, but reading the documentation, this is something to be aware.